# In R: party package error

Tags: r

I have a problem running the party package. I made sure it is loaded using sessionInfo() where I can see that party_1.0-20 is an attached package. When I try to run the examples I found in the internet like:

```
cf <- cforest(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
```

I get this error:

> Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
>     cannot use object of class “integer” in new():  class “ExpectCovarInfluence” does not extend that class

I tried with other data sets, but get the same error.

Comment: I do get an error but not that one

Comment: What version of R are you running? I was able to successfully run on R 3.2. Also, it looks like cforest will run into issues with a small number of predictors - I needed at least 5 predictors to get it to run without warnings.

Comment: `dput(cars)` pls, if it is not very large. If it is large, it would be helpful to try subsetting a small part of it which preserves the problem, which makes a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Here : http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/party/docs/cforest they mention "The number of randomly preselected variables mtry, which is fixed to the value 5 by default here for technical reasons".

That seems to be the case using this example:

```
library(party)

dt = data.frame(mtcars)

cforest(disp ~ wt, data = dt)

# Random Forest using Conditional Inference Trees
# 
# Number of trees:  500 
# 
# Response:  disp 
# Input:  wt 
# Number of observations:  32 
# 
# There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)  #### see the warnings!!


cforest(disp ~ wt+mpg+cyl+vs+gear, data = dt)

# Random Forest using Conditional Inference Trees
# 
# Number of trees:  500 
# 
# Response:  disp 
# Inputs:  wt, mpg, cyl, vs, gear 
# Number of observations:  32
```

Maybe it would be better to start using this:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/randomForest

Comment: The random forest package works fine! But I wanted to use a function for conditional importance that is only available in the party package... I tried the suggested code "cforest(disp ~ wt+mpg+cyl+vs+gear, data = dt)", but I still get the same error.